# JQuery drop down bobs up and down continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to hide/show an DIV on hover of an LI. When I do this the div appeared but pops up and down without stopping until I take my mouse off the LI.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.menu_head').mouseover(function () {
       $('div.newsadviceDrop').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show this in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You likely mouseout and over when it opens

Comment: Did you try `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`? `mouseover` causes trouble sometimes.

Comment: Yes http://jsfiddle.net/F59un/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.menu_head').hover(function () {
        $('div.newsadviceDrop').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** To keep it open until you mouse over again do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.menu_head').mouseenter(function () {
        $('div.newsadviceDrop').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

Comment: This stops the bobbing up and down but when my mouse stops hoving over the LI the element goes away again.

Comment: If you want to have it so it opens when you mouse over, and closes when you mouse over again use `.mouseenter` I edited my example to showcase this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .mouseenter instead of .mouseover

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue like that with "mouseover".

Try "mouseenter" instead...

OR...

just use the jQuery hover()

**EDIT:**

**silent1mezzo** submitted the best/correct answer first.

Answer (score 0):

While the mouse is over `li.menu_head`, you will repeatedly call `.slideToggle`, which explains why you see the continuous behaviour. You could perhaps replace this with behaviour on `mouseenter` and `mouseexit`.